# passing an arguement through a sqllite query in python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

hi i currently writing a function that saves data to a database where the database and data are specified as arguments but i am unsure how to include the arguments with the sql query. i am using sqlite3 for this function and the code i currently have is

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect(ID+'.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    if date_check(current_date(), all_dates(ID)) is True:
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO "ID" VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)''', data)
        conn.commit()
        c.close()
        conn.close()
    else:
        pass
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is well documented with examples in the [python sqlite3 API doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at how to format strings: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples  This allows you to insert variables (elements of your `data` variable) into your query string.

Comment: @J.Rimmer be very, very careful. If the replacement data is coming from user input (like an html form), this approach can make your system vulnerable to SQL injection, a serious threat to your database and system.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @DinoCoderSaurus. Forgot to mention it

Comment: yes i may have to put some input validation in at some point luckily it is only a little project i am doing thank you for your help

Comment: If your need something more robust, I can recommend https://www.sqlalchemy.org/